# How can I generate custom colors using AnyChart?

Tags: javascript, anychart

How can I generate custom colors using AnyChart?

This is what I have so far. I've commented the line, which refers to the palette - 'Trying to affect palette here'.

```
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {

  //Trying to affect palette here
  //led.palette = anychart.palettes.earth;

  // create a stage
  stage = anychart.graphics.create("diagramContainer");

  // create data
  var data = [170, 210, 130, 310];

  // set the gauge type
  led = anychart.gauges.led();

  // set data for the gauge
  led.data(data);

  // add the default pointer
  led.addPointer(2);

  // set the size and position
  led.bounds("50%", 0, "25%", "100%");

  // sets background settings.
  led.background({fill: "#FFFFFF 0.0"});

  // sets left bound.
  led.left("28%");

  // sets height.
  led.height("35%");

  // set the container id
  led.container(stage);

  // initiate the gauge drawing
  led.draw();
```

});

Answer (score 1):

I think you can directly modify color items in an existing palette:

```
  let palette = anychart.palettes.distinctColors();
  palette.items(
      ['#00FF00', '#FFFF00', '#FFA500', '#FF0000','#F0F0F0', '#101010']
  );
  // create a tag cloud chart
  var chart = anychart.tagCloud(data);
  chart.background({fill: "#2F2F2F 3.5"});
  chart.palette(palette);
  //...
  chart.draw()
```

Answer (score 0):

Palette is not a property, it is a method, as pretty much everything in AnyChart, here is how it is done: http://jsfiddle.net/0vhvnjqp/

```
// apply palette
led.palette(anychart.palettes.earth);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete code with custom color in anychart

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/js/7.14.3/anychart-bundle.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.anychart.com/css/7.14.3/anychart-ui.min.css" />
  <style>
    html, body, #container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {
  // create column chart
  chart = anychart.column3d();
  chart.background({fill: "#000000 3.5"});
  //chart.Color("blue");
  // turn on chart animation
  chart.animation(true);

  // set chart title text settings
  chart.title('Top 10 Cosmetic Products by Revenue');

  // create area series with passed data
  chart.column([
    ['Rouge', '80'],
    ['Foundation', '9'],
    ['Mascara', '10'],
    ['Lip gloss', '11'],
    ['Pomade', '12'],
    ['Nail polish', '14'],
    ['Eyebrow pencil', '17'],
    ['Eyeliner', '21'],
    ['Eyeshadows', '24']
  ]).fill('red');

  chart.tooltip()
    .position('top')
    .anchor('bottom')
    .offsetX(0)
    .offsetY(5)
    .format('{%Value}%');

  // set scale minimum
  chart.yScale().minimum(0);

  // set yAxis labels formatter
  chart.yAxis().labels().format('{%Value}{groupsSeparator: }');

  chart.tooltip().positionMode('point');
  chart.interactivity().hoverMode('byX');

  chart.xAxis().title('Products by Revenue');
  chart.yAxis().title('Revenue in Dollars');

  // set container id for the chart
  chart.container('container');
  var yLabels1 = chart.yAxis().labels();
    yLabels1.format(function(){
      return this.value + "%";
    });
  // initiate chart drawing
  chart.draw();
});
    </script>
</body>
</html
```

>